# Add Max and Average in linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've got an sql query below:

```
SELECT MAX(r.Suburb), AVG(s.Longitude) AS Longitude, AVG(s.Latitude) AS Latitude 
From CafeAddress r inner join Cafe s on s.CafeId = r.CafeId
WHERE r.Region = 'Sydney'
```

which outputs:

```
Bankstown   174.759541622222    -36.8552809611111
```

The query should be getting all suburbs in the region e.g. Sydney is the region and suburbs would include Bankstown etc..

How would I add max and average in my linq query below? (region id is a user input (string))

```
var region = from cafeAddress in _context.CafeAddress
                         join cafe in _context.Cafe on cafeAddress.CafeId equals cafe.CafeId
                         where cafeAddress.StateProvinceRegion == regionId
                         select new { StateProvinceRegion = cafeAddress.Suburb.Max(), cafe.Latitude,  cafe.Longitude };
```

I'm only able to do it through using a group by but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: What does `MAX(r.City)` mean when `City` is a string?

Comment: Also your SQL uses `City`, but the LINQ shows `StateProvinceRegion` & `Suburb`. It's very confusing. Can you please fix?

Comment: so max will get the largest "city" value which is something I found that works instead of using group by

Comment: @Enigmativity from the docs: *For character columns, MAX finds the highest value in the collating sequence*. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Updated my question hopefully it's a bit more clear now :)

Comment: So the region is `Sydney` and the suburb is `Sydney`? Seems odd still.

Comment: There are places around the world where the suburb has the same name as the region it just pretty much means it's the central part of the region. I changed the question to make it more clear

Comment: Just to clarify, is the SQL query producing desired results, and the goal is to do the same via a LINQ query, but without any `GroupBy`s?

Comment: Yup the query is providing the desired results - and yes the goal is to do it the same via linq query without any groupBy s

Comment: I really don't think it's doable in LINQ in a single query...

Comment: @rey123 - Why? You'd have to pull back all of the data and do it client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be getting fairly close:

```
var query =
    from cafeAddress in _context.CafeAddress
    join cafe in _context.Cafe on cafeAddress.CafeId equals cafe.CafeId
    where cafeAddress.StateProvinceRegion == regionId
    orderby cafeAddress.Suburb descending
    group new
    {
        cafeAddress.Suburb,
        cafe.Latitude,
        cafe.Longitude
    } by cafeAddress.StateProvinceRegion into g
    select new
    {
        StateProvinceRegion = g.First().Suburb,
        Latitude = g.Average(x => x.Latitude),
        Longitude = g.Average(x => x.Longitude),
    };
```

Or this slight variant:

```
var query =
    from cafeAddress in _context.CafeAddress
    join cafe in _context.Cafe on cafeAddress.CafeId equals cafe.CafeId
    where cafeAddress.StateProvinceRegion == regionId
    orderby cafeAddress.Suburb descending
    group new
    {
        cafeAddress.Suburb,
        cafe.Latitude,
        cafe.Longitude
    } by cafeAddress.StateProvinceRegion into gs
    from g in gs.Take(1)
    select new
    {
        StateProvinceRegion = g.Suburb,
        Latitude = gs.Average(x => x.Latitude),
        Longitude = gs.Average(x => x.Longitude),
    };
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it without using group by

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `group by`?

Comment: @rey123 you have no choice, you are either left with running 3 queries, writing a raw sql query, or GroupBy which is the only way to get multiple aggregates in linq to entities

Comment: yeah I'll probably have to stick with groupby then